# Using contenteditable with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, contenteditable

I have a div

```
<div id="content_x" class="something" contenteditable="true">
```

In fact I have several of these, hence the class name. When class `something` is edited, I get the id using some regex magic `id = $(this).attr('id');`

How can I check that the content of this textarea has changed, because I want to send this via regex.

I can get the old value, but how do I get the old value?

```
$('.something').click(function() {
  $('.something').change();

});
```

I've also heard of this plugin: http://valums.com/edit-in-place/ however this places buttons in your divs. I want the new value when the user clicks away from the div.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
var contentWhenPageLoaded = document.getElementById("content_x").innerHTML;

//Then you can check if the content has changed like this:
if(contentWhenPageLoaded != document.getElementById("content_x").innerHTML) {
  alert("content has changed!");
}
```